# Android Studio - After clicking button current activity reopens

Tags: java, android, xml, button

My problem is that I have one activity `Transport`. There, I have a button `Auto`. When I click on `Auto` the `activity_auto` should be opened. But instead the `activity_transport` reopens.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong?!
Can someone please help me?

activity_Transport

```
package com.group6.travlhoe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by STzavelas on 29.06.17.
 */

public class activity_transport extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button btnAuto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transport);

        btnAuto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Auto);
        btnAuto.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.Auto:
                Intent i = new Intent(activity_transport.this, activity_auto.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

The XML-File of Transport-Class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hintergrund">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Auto"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:background="@mipmap/buttom_col"
            android:text="Auto"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Flugzeug"
            android:alpha="0.9"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/buttom_col"
            android:text="Flugzeug"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Taxi"
            android:alpha="0.9"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/buttom_col"
            android:text="Taxi"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bahn"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:text="Bahn"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/buttom_col" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow" />


        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
            design:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    </FrameLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Error Details:

```
06-29 20:32:33.820 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:34:51.703 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:35:48.666 1515-1583/? E/HalDeviceManager: getAllChipInfo: called but mWifi is null!?
06-29 20:35:48.666 1515-1583/? E/HalDeviceManager: getSupportedIfaceTypesInternal: no chip info found
06-29 20:35:48.667 1515-1532/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
06-29 20:35:48.667 1515-1532/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
06-29 20:35:48.672 1515-1532/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
06-29 20:35:48.672 1515-1532/? E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
06-29 20:35:48.672 1515-1532/? E/KernelUidCpuFreqTimeReader: Failed to read /proc/uid_time_in_state: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_time_in_state (No such file or directory)
06-29 20:35:48.676 1515-1532/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
06-29 20:36:00.006 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:36:43.785 1515-1536/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 60)
06-29 20:36:43.801 1515-2337/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 56)
06-29 20:36:43.825 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'fb02237 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.830 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '42e3da5 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.830 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '9caaf46 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_transport (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.830 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '62733b com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_transport (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.831 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '8d0c4b8 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.831 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b93000 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.831 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'e7536cd com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_transport (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.831 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f37b6cf com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.831 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f4b06f5 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_transport (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.831 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '7e757ea com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.831 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '68a5e48 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_transport (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:36:43.919 1515-1536/? E/ViewRootImpl[travlhoe]: Attempting to destroy the window while drawing!
                                                           window=android.view.ViewRootImpl@5f4980, title=Splash Screen com.group6.travlhoe
06-29 20:36:44.063 1349-1365/? E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (4 threads) starved for 103 ms
06-29 20:36:44.336 2261-4816/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
06-29 20:36:44.690 2145-4527/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerStatusImpl]updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=7
06-29 20:36:44.944 2124-2124/? E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'localabstract:com.group6.travlhoe': Connection refused
06-29 20:36:47.320 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:36:49.436 2261-4816/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
06-29 20:36:54.783 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:36:55.181 1415-1571/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl771514638.tmp: No such file or directory
06-29 20:36:55.493 2145-4822/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
06-29 20:36:55.493 2145-4822/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
06-29 20:36:55.729 2261-4770/? E/ContentStoreEUAS: Failed to commit the deferred actions
06-29 20:36:56.104 2602-2602/? E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
06-29 20:36:56.125 2145-4822/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
06-29 20:36:56.125 2145-4822/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
06-29 20:36:57.030 1349-1365/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-29 20:36:59.530 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:37:00.003 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:00.016 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:02.152 4897-4897/com.group6.travlhoe E/Transport: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{a2ac0e1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,533 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}
06-29 20:37:03.973 4897-4897/com.group6.travlhoe E/Transport: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{6c39ce6 VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,533 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}
06-29 20:37:04.801 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:37:12.622 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:15.050 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:15.062 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:15.493 4897-4897/com.group6.travlhoe E/Transport: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{48ba4a VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,533 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}
06-29 20:37:17.766 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:18.997 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:37:25.215 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:27.493 2145-2509/? E/UidImportanceUtils: exception when invoking removeOnUidImportanceListener
                                                     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at alvy.a(:com.google.android.gms:1123)
                                                         at akva.a(:com.google.android.gms:44820)
                                                         at lsx.a(:com.google.android.gms:246)
                                                         at akuy.run(:com.google.android.gms:2812)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                         at alxb.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms:3028)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Listener not registered: alvz@dee348d
                                                         at android.app.ActivityManager.removeOnUidImportanceListener(ActivityManager.java:3628)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                         at alvy.a(:com.google.android.gms:1123) 
                                                         at akva.a(:com.google.android.gms:44820) 
                                                         at lsx.a(:com.google.android.gms:246) 
                                                         at akuy.run(:com.google.android.gms:2812) 
                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769) 
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                         at alxb.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms:3028) 
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 
06-29 20:37:27.799 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:27.810 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:32.499 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:44.009 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:37:44.026 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:38:00.002 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:38:33.601 1515-1536/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 60)
06-29 20:38:33.611 1515-1525/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 56)
06-29 20:38:33.641 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'da3c079 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:38:33.642 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b0c44cd com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:38:33.642 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '6dda3ce com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_transport (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:38:33.642 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'edd48a3 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_transport (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:38:33.642 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '5d39600 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:38:33.642 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '94554f5 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_transport (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:38:33.642 1515-1572/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f821460 com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-29 20:38:33.749 1515-1536/? E/ViewRootImpl[travlhoe]: Attempting to destroy the window while drawing!
                                                           window=android.view.ViewRootImpl@f58dbf0, title=Splash Screen com.group6.travlhoe
06-29 20:38:34.065 2261-4771/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
06-29 20:38:34.367 2145-4526/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerStatusImpl]updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=7
06-29 20:38:37.124 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:38:39.160 2261-4771/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
06-29 20:38:43.839 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:38:43.944 1415-1434/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl623981594.tmp: No such file or directory
06-29 20:38:44.118 2145-4822/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
06-29 20:38:44.118 2145-4822/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
06-29 20:38:44.311 2261-4771/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
06-29 20:38:44.577 6329-6336/? E/zygote: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
06-29 20:38:44.607 2261-6344/? E/ContentStoreEUAS: Failed to commit the deferred actions
06-29 20:38:44.695 1610-1631/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.group6.travlhoe-Y2EMoG6jUjwUupyHVUqE9Q==/base.apk
06-29 20:38:44.696 1610-1631/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.group6.travlhoe-Y2EMoG6jUjwUupyHVUqE9Q==/base.apk
06-29 20:38:44.701 1610-1631/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.group6.travlhoe-Y2EMoG6jUjwUupyHVUqE9Q==/base.apk
06-29 20:38:44.702 1610-1631/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.group6.travlhoe-Y2EMoG6jUjwUupyHVUqE9Q==/base.apk
06-29 20:38:44.708 1610-1631/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.group6.travlhoe-Y2EMoG6jUjwUupyHVUqE9Q==/base.apk
06-29 20:38:44.778 2602-2602/? E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
06-29 20:38:44.832 2145-4527/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
06-29 20:38:44.832 2145-4527/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
06-29 20:38:45.812 1349-2308/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-29 20:38:48.281 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:38:52.567 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:38:52.581 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:38:52.591 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:38:55.691 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:38:57.432 6329-6329/com.group6.travlhoe E/Transport: android.widget.Button{5d35365 VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,589 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}
06-29 20:38:59.184 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:38:59.485 6329-6329/com.group6.travlhoe E/Transport: android.widget.Button{fd4cc2f VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,589 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}
06-29 20:39:02.987 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:39:14.017 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:39:14.029 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:39:14.665 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:39:16.298 2145-2509/? E/UidImportanceUtils: exception when invoking removeOnUidImportanceListener
                                                     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at alvy.a(:com.google.android.gms:1123)
                                                         at akva.a(:com.google.android.gms:44820)
                                                         at lsx.a(:com.google.android.gms:246)
                                                         at akuy.run(:com.google.android.gms:2812)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                         at alxb.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms:3028)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Listener not registered: alvz@dee348d
                                                         at android.app.ActivityManager.removeOnUidImportanceListener(ActivityManager.java:3628)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                         at alvy.a(:com.google.android.gms:1123) 
                                                         at akva.a(:com.google.android.gms:44820) 
                                                         at lsx.a(:com.google.android.gms:246) 
                                                         at akuy.run(:com.google.android.gms:2812) 
                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769) 
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                         at alxb.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms:3028) 
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 
06-29 20:39:21.305 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:39:21.321 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:39:26.207 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:40:00.003 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:40:00.029 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:41:00.002 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:41:42.245 6329-6329/com.group6.travlhoe E/Transport: android.widget.Button{9046266 VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,589 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}
06-29 20:41:45.746 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:41:49.101 6329-6329/com.group6.travlhoe E/Transport: android.widget.Button{a1aa735 VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,589 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}
06-29 20:41:52.605 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:43:00.006 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:43:00.046 1347-1347/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/2458/oom_score_adj; errno=22
06-29 20:43:00.051 1515-1762/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 76)
06-29 20:43:00.057 1515-1762/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 304)
06-29 20:43:00.068 1515-1762/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 76)
06-29 20:45:00.006 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:45:12.598 6329-6329/com.group6.travlhoe E/Transport: android.widget.Button{7790b6d VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,589 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}
06-29 20:45:16.101 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:45:23.979 6329-6329/com.group6.travlhoe E/Transport: android.widget.Button{8d30e07 VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,589 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}
06-29 20:45:27.485 1515-1603/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
06-29 20:47:00.009 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:48:00.007 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:49:00.008 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:51:00.010 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:52:00.003 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:52:15.067 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:52:15.078 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:53:00.006 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:53:00.021 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:54:00.002 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:54:00.028 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-29 20:54:00.040 1515-1528/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

Activity Auto.class

```
package com.group6.travlhoe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class activity_auto extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto);

        ImageButton btnCamera= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){
                if (item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_start){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_auto.this, MainActivity.class));
                } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_allgemein){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_auto.this, activity_allgemein.class));
                } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_transport){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_auto.this, activity_transport.class));
                } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_rechnung){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_auto.this, activity_rechnung.class));
                } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_unterkunft){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_auto.this, activity_unterkunft.class));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_transport);
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btnCamera) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.goToGPS) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(activity_auto.this, function_gps.class );
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: apparently `activity_auto.class` is causing a crash , look for logcat error details

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh how do you know this? Where can I look for the logcat error details? Sorry I am pretty new in programming..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: should I look for error details within the auto.class ??

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I implemented the Log.e in my switch statement:
Log.e(TAG, view.toString());
This is the error I get:
E/Transport: android.widget.Button{8d30e07 VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,589 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}

Do you know what that means? Google has no good answers in that case..

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I did, please see above

Comment: post the code of `ctivity_auto.class`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no error , you are by default telling your `BottomNavigatonView` to select the 3rd menu mean execute this case

```
else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_transport){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_auto.this, activity_transport.class));
                }
```

which will open your `activity_transport.class` activity so simple

**remove** this line `bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_transport);`

Comment: oh man, you are genius thank you so much!!!!!! i was sitting in front of this problem the whole day thank you

Comment: i am glad that i could help